# Как изменить размер изображения до определенной величины

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения

Есть изображение. Весит 10мб. Хочу уменьшит размер до 2мб. Есть ли решение которое позволит точно это сделать? На данный момент я вижу это решение. Но мне все равно кажется что это не есть хорошее решение.

```
while (изображение !=2мб)
{
     изображение =уменьшитьФото(величина);
     величина++;
}
```

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Winforms.........

Comment: пример [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/648716/csharp-image-resize-with-new-bitmap-vs-draw-image)

Comment: Ну там просто код который ресайзит) а мне нужно по умному

Comment: после ресайза смотрите bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height, и повторите ресайз.

Comment: @Stack можно и заранее размер угадать, зная количество байт на пиксель и соотношение сторон

Comment: @PashaPash _"размер угадать, зная количество байт на пиксель и соотношение сторон"_ -- если делается ресайз с минимальной потерей качества, то для этого меняют SmoothingMode, PixelOffsetMode, CompositingQuality, CompositingMode, WrapMode и Resolution. после такого угадать мне кажется не получится.

Comment: @Stack это все свойста Graphics, влияющие на качество отрисовки - они не влияют на рамер битмапа. А Stride (Width) / Height, которые вы предложили использовать - это просто размер самого битмапа. Он не зависит от того, как хорошо сглажен текст на картинке. Т.е. bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height от перечисленных вами параметров не зависит. Другое дело что топикастер скорее всего хочет получить размер картинки не в BMP, а в PNG/JPG, а его заранее подобрать нельзя.

Comment: @PashaPash _"а в PNG/JPG, а его заранее подобрать нельзя."_ -- а если после ресайза получить byte[] или сохранить в MemoryStream и получить Length?

Comment: @Stack я про это и говорю - можно *померять* после ресайза, но нельзя угадать размер *до* ресайза. Т.е. для BMP, например, зная что соотношение сторон исходной картинки 3/4, и пиксель занимает 3 байта, можно высчитать размер заранее (sqrt( (2*1024*1024 - 54) / 3 / 12 ) = 241, умножить на 3, и 4 -> 723*964, 2,093,862 байт). *Любая* картинка с соотношением 3/4 после ресайза в 723*964 и сохранения в 24 bit bmp займет 2,093,862 байт. А для jpg / png размер заранее, до ресайза и сжатия, угадать нельзя. максимум - сжимать в цикле, подбирая размер дихотомией, пока не попадет в пределы 2-х мегабайт.